# Huawei E3372 force me to show a webpage on my raspberry pi 2

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I have some Raspberry Pi 2 that launch a webpage on Epiphany at startup. I get internet connection with some 4g Modem Huawei E3372. Those modems are setup to launch 192.168.8.1/html/home.html at startup so it mess with the webpage that I want to show. This happens just on some Huawei Modems so I think this may be configurable but I don't now where.

How can I deal with this behavior?

Can I route 192.168.8.1/html/home.html to my webpage or something?

Can I setup the Huawei modem to deactivate this behavior?

Is there a way to get the URL from Epiphany to check if there is showing the correct webpage and if not change it?

Answer (score 1):

The Huawei E3372 (both the older E3372s and newer E3372h), without any change in model number or exterior appearance, comes in two versions: "HiLink mode" where it is configured with a web interface and works like a router accessed by IP address, and "Stick mode", where it acts as a regular mobile broadband modem.

Yours is in HiLink mode, and the webpage that pops up is the page to configure it.

Changing it from HiLink to stick mode is possible by exchanging the firmware, but it's a somewhat difficult procedure. I did not try it myself yet, but the best set of instructions seem to be [these](http://blog.asiantuntijakaveri.fi/2015/07/convert-huawei-e3372h-153-from.html). They are only meant for the E3372h though.